# CORS Issue: Unable to send post request using NodeJs and Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, api, rest, express

I am getting this message when trying to send a post request:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:3002/api/products/checkout' from origin 
'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field content-type 
is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Right now I'm simply trying to send data to my backend and then log it in the console. Get requests work fine but for some reason I get that CORS error when trying post. Here is my code:

Angular code:

```
//api call
return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/api/checkout', cart)
```

NodeJs code:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Header', 
        'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
    res.setHeader(
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 
        'GET, POST, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');
    next();
})

app.post("/api/checkout", (req, res, next) => {
    const cart = req.body;
    console.log(cart)
    res.status(201).json()
})

module.exports = app;
```

In the network calls I can see that Request Headers is:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: content-type
```

while Response Headers is:

```
Access-Control-Request-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept
```

I'm not sure if content-type being lower case has anything to do with the issue.

Comment: Share the *actual* headers. Copy paste them from the network tab. Currently the headers you say you send in Node, are *not* the same as the headers that you say you say in the Network tab. Headers are case insensitive, so that should not be an issue.

Comment: Note that the request that's failing is the `OPTIONS` request

Comment: instead of making your own cors handler just use express cors for this https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html then you can setup allowed urls or for a start just allow everything and configure it correct when in production.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `req.set` instead, just change `setHeader` to `set` only. Here is the document https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.set

And if you just using localhost, there's another easier option, you can use `proxy`. More information can be found here https://angular.io/guide/build#proxying-to-a-backend-server

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem that you wrote *Access-Control-Allow-Header* instead of *Access-Control-Allow-Header**s***, but I cannot test it now.

Be aware that you need to serve `OPTIONS` requests too. Which is just responding with an empty message body using the same headers. You can get these kind of `OPTIONS` requests before `PUT, PATCH, DELETE` from certain HTTP clients e.g. from browsers too.